# Determine position of a new column while creating it

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I just want to put a new column I am creating to the start of a dataframe instead of it appearing at the end. All the answers I have read use 'insert' which I am using in my current solution but I think it is unnecessarily complicated. I am sure there's a better solution.

I am creating a column concatenating 2 columns.

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
df_temp['Result_ID'] =df['ID']+'_'+df['Execution_Date'].dt.month.astype(str) + df['Execution_Date'].dt.day.astype(str) + df['Execution_Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
```

```
df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'Result_ID', value = df_temp )
```

How can I directly insert this new column in df at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `concat`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Result_ID': df_temp},index=df.index),df],axis=1)
```

Comment: Hey could you explain the code? The point was to do it without creating a df_temp. The Result_ID column is just a concatenation of the ID and the execution_date column (1st block of code). I would like to add Result_ID directly to start of df without creating df_temp

Comment: @Dhruv if that is the case why not just df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'Result_ID', value = df['ID']+'_'+df['Execution_Date'].dt.month.astype(str) + df['Execution_Date'].dt.day.astype(str) + df['Execution_Date'].dt.year.astype(str) )

Answer (score 0):

since df_temp is dataframe with one column and `df_temp` and `df` have same index you may use `join`

```
df_temp.join(df)
```

if you already assigned `'Result_ID'` column to the end of `df`, you may use `set_index` and `reset_index`

```
df.set_index('Result_ID').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column at the beginning of the dataframe using `reindex`as follows,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,4],[4,3],[5,3]], columns = ['A', 'B'])
new = [3,4,4]
```

```
df.reindex(['C', *df.columns], axis=1).assign(C=new)
df
```

Hope it helps.
However, I think, `insert` would be easier to deal with provided additional flexibility to play with the data,

```
df.insert(0, 'C',new )
df
```